# How to get the returned value from a method from within the method?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I've been practicing some algorithms with ruby for a while, and I'm wondering if it is possible to catch the returned value from within the method.

the code below is to reverse a string without any kind of reverse method and with few local variables...

```
def rev(a)
 i = -1
 a.split("").each do |el|
  el[0] = a[i]
  i = i + (-1)
 end.join
end
```

Note that the result of the 'each' method is not being assigned to any variable. So, 'each' evaluates to an array with a reversed sequence of characters. At the 'end' (literally) I've just 'called' the method 'join' to glue everything together. The idea is to 'catch' the returned value from all this process and check if is true or false that the reversed string is a palindrome.

If the reversed string is equal to the original one then the word is a palindrome. Ex. "abba", "sexes", "radar"...

for example:

```
def rev(a)
 i = -1
 a.split("").each do |el|
  el[0] = a[i]
  i = i + (-1)
 end.join
 # catch here the returned value from the code above
 # and check if its a palindrome or not. (true or false)
end
```

Thank you guys! I will be very grateful if anyone could help me figure out this!

Comment: Do you mean using [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)?, are you aware you can check a palindrome just by comparing the string with its reverse version?

Comment: Yeah I know! but I was practicing some algorithms without using methods that does all the job for us. challenging myself! Thanks Buddy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `== a` to see if your reversal matches the original string:

```
def rev(a)
 i = -1
 a.split("").each do |el|
  el[0] = a[i]
  i = i + (-1)
 end.join == a
end

puts rev("racecar") # => true
puts rev("racecars") # => false
```

An easier way to check palindromes (`rev` could be better named `palindrome?`) is `a == a.reverse` since `.reverse` is essentially what your `split`/`each`/`join` does.

Comment: Thanks my friend! :) It would be nice if ruby had some kind of method to retrieve that value...

Comment: Which value do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you want back all the information, you can return an array with both the values:

```
def rev(a)
 i = -1
 rev = a.split("").each do |el|
  el[0] = a[i]
  i = i + (-1)
 end.join
 [rev, rev == a] # or
 # return rev, rev == a
end

p rev("abra") #=> ["arba", false]
p rev("abba") #=> ["abba", true]
```

You can also return a hash:

```
{ reverse: rev, palindrome: rev == a}
```

to get

```
#=> {:reverse=>"arba", :palindrome=>false}
#=> {:reverse=>"abba", :palindrome=>true}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of other ways you could reverse a string.

**#1**

```
def esrever(str)
  s = str.dup
  (str.size/2).times { |i| s[i], s[-1-i] = s[-1-i], s[i] }
  s
end

esrever("abcdefg")
  #=> "gfedcba"
esrever("racecar")
  #=> "racecar"
```

This uses *parallel assignment* (sometimes called *multiple assignment*).

**#2**

```
def esrever(str)
  a = str.chars
  ''.tap { |s| str.size.times { s << a.pop } }
end

esrever("abcdefg")
  #=> "gfedcba"
esrever("racecar")
  #=> "racecar"
```

I've used [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) merely to avoid creating a local variable initialized to an empty string and then having to make that variable the last line of the method.

With both methods a string `str` is a palindrome if and only if `str == esrever(str)`.